# Reporting day of the month using the FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Good night people.
I have the following questions:
It is possible to inform the days of the month fullcallendar the day inves. Example

```
5, 6 and 7 October 2016
```

My need is that the agenda of my employee is not from Monday to Friday (Saturday or Sunday) but for days of the month ... another example of work:

```
Days: 10,11,15, 21
```

Here is my current code:

```
businessHours: [
 { 
  start: '8:00', 
  end: '12:00', 
  dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
 }, { 
  start: '13:00', 
  end: '24:00', 
  dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
 }
]
```

How would I do that?

Comment: `code` businessHours:
                            [{
                                    start: '8:00',
                                    end: '12:00',
                                    dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
                                },
                                {
                                    start: '13:00',
                                    end: '24:00',
                                    dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
                                }],`code`

Comment: @alljamin I think you have not to do this. I may have to create an event for the dates do not wish to have events ... example: 5th day of work ... then 1 to 4 create event and 6-30 as well.